# Pattern matching case when

Tags: c#, .net, pattern-matching, c#-7.0

I write simple math tokenizer and try to use new C# `pattern matching` feature.

Tokenizer is quite simple:

```
    public IEnumerable<IToken> Tokenize(string input)
    {
        const char decimalSeparator = '.';
        string inputWithoutSpaces = input.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
        var numberBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        var letterBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in inputWithoutSpaces)
        {
            switch (c)
            {
                case var _ when IsTerm(c, letterBuffer):
                    if (numberBuffer.Length > 0)
                    {
                        yield return EmptyNumberBufferAsLiteral(numberBuffer);
                        yield return new Operator('*');
                    }
                    letterBuffer.Append(c);
                    break;
                case decimalSeparator:
                case var _ when IsDigit(c):
                    numberBuffer.Append(c);
                    break;
                case var _ when IsOperator(c):
                    if (numberBuffer.Length > 0)
                    {
                        yield return EmptyNumberBufferAsLiteral(numberBuffer);
                    }
                    if (letterBuffer.Length > 0)
                    {
                        yield return EmptyLetterBufferAsTerm(letterBuffer);
                    }
                    yield return new Operator(c);
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (numberBuffer.Length > 0)
        {
            yield return EmptyNumberBufferAsLiteral(numberBuffer);
        }
        if (letterBuffer.Length > 0)
        {
            yield return EmptyLetterBufferAsTerm(letterBuffer);
        }
    }
```

I'm using `case var _` because I want to match by condition without using `if-else if` chain, but I'm unable to write `case when` without specifying `var variableName`.

Is there any fancy way to perform such operation? Or it is recommended way to do these things?

Comment: Well you're sort of abusing pattern matching to get around the requirement of using constants in switch statements so there's no real way to get around it. Additionally, I think your logic probably fits/reads better as if/else statements anyway.

Comment: @DavidG on the contrary, that looks like Active Patterns, which make the implementation of tokenizers and parsers a lot easier. Pattern matching in C# 7 misses several important features. Active patterns is one of them. I'd dive higher priority to exhaustive matching though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, but I'm talking about what is available right now in the language. I'm pretty sure we'll see a lot more pattern matching stuff coming into C# in the future (thanks mainly to F# I would assume)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "fancy" way to do pattern matching like this, using what are commonly called active patterns. C# doesn't (yet) support active patterns though, but [see this answer for an example of what they might look like if/when implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42952570/7122).

So using active patterns, your code would end up looking something like:

```
switch (c)
{
    case Term(letterBuffer):
        ...
        break;
    case decimalSeparator:
    case Digit():
        ...
        break;
    case Operator():
        ...
        break;
}
```

If you'd like to see this feature in a future version of C#, [please upvote it on the csharplang github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/277).

In the meantime, then you are limited choosing between sticking with `if` statements as others have said, or using when guards as you are. Which you go for really is just a matter of preferred style.

Comment: I'd rather see exhaustive matching implemented first, to prevent "missed" cases.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos agree completely. Unfortunately I think we are going to see proper pattern matching pushed back in favour of a bunch of other OO-related features. So the Op's pseudo-active patterns will be the way to do for some time.